# Are there any illegal characters in MySQL which may not be stored in a field?

Tags: mysql, hex, ascii, character

I'm looking for a shorthand solution to storing an md5 hash inside of a MySQL table, as string data. I had the idea that base256 could reduce the length of the string by half, down to a 16 digit string instead of 32 digits of hex. So I take hex and divide it up into chunks of two digits programatically then convert each set of two digits to ASCII. For example:

```
4cf5f5941a02573dc007e60442f5358a
```

is shortened to

```
Lõõ”W=ÀæBõ5Š
```

and it's OK if these characters don't *print* properly - I just need to store them. Would MySQL accept that sort of ASCII data into a text field without complaining?

Comment: Are binary/varbinary columns out of consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will accept these values, but you must be very carefull when writing them - I strongly suggest binding parameters.

You might want to look into `COMPRESS()` and `UNCOMPRESS()` as an alternative:

```
INSERT INTO ... SET hashcode=COMPRESS('4cf5f5941a02573dc007e60442f5358a');
```

and

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(hashcode) AS hashcode FROM ... WHERE
```

might do the trick more readable

Comment: One more: You can SELECT by compressed hashcodes: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE hashcode=COMPRESS('4cf5f5941a02573dc007e60442f5358a');` will work as expected.